# Не работает значение repeat у свойства background

Tags: css, background

Необходимо поставить бесшовный фон на сайт. Скачиваю картинку небольшого размера, прописываю в CSS `background-image: url (); repeat;`, но какую картинку бы я не ставил, любая из них очень сильно растягивается и вместо четкого фона состоящего из небольших узоров бесшовных, получается что картинка размером 20х20 растягивается на весь экран и получается уродство.

Какие свойства прописать что бы это исправить?

Comment: по умолчанию достаточно задать только background-image, покажите картинку. Возможно у вас картинка 2х или где-то еще прописан background-size

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, пробел-то всё равно всё испортит, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy, кстати да

Answer (score 4):

Скорее всего сайт работает на каком-то готовом шаблоне. И свойство, растягивающее картинку на весь экран тоже там уже прописано. Соответственно - надо не добавлять, а убрать свойство растягивающее картинку на весь экран.

Открывайте инспектор кода и ищите где у вас уже прописано свойство `background-size`.

Далее - можно либо удалить это свойство, либо прописать `background-size: auto !important;`, либо задать правилу больший [приоритет с помощью селекторов](https://htmlacademy.ru/courses/66/run/15)

Answer (score 0):

```
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: 100%;
```

Comment: попробовал,не помогает.

Comment: `background-size: 100%;` как раз и растянет картинку на весь экран

Answer (score 0):

Если  `background-repeat: repeat !important;` прописанный в CSS не отменяет, то если лень искать его? Где он прописан, тогда уж прописать его прямо в HTML

```
<tag style="background-repeat: repeat !important; background-size: auto;"></tag>
```

В данном случае, он отменит все и будет читать только это правило... 
А если он прописан где-то ещё в JS...
То добавь в JS строку elem.style.backgroundSize = '100%';
И что бы данный файл JS был ниже всех прописан в body прямо над тегом body

Тогда это правило будет читаться последним и его не должно ничего изменить

Comment: ну про js вы погорячились. если он там ставится, то перезапишется.

Comment: вы просто в js косякнули, просто 100% поставьте - https://jsfiddle.net/b7wk6ktu/

Comment: гляньте мой фиддл по ссылке выше)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> background-image: url (); repeat;
> ```

1. Убери пробел перед скобкой
2. Поменяй `background-image` на `background`
3. Убери точку с запятой перед `repeat`

```css
html, body, div {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background: url(//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG) repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```